# How to track Google Analytics of Adobe Air app?

Tags: google-analytics, flash, flash-builder

I have written an Adobe Air desktop application that tracks a bunch of websites and displays images from the websites in the app. I'd like to make it so that the webmasters can see that page views are made by my application.

Is there any way the webmaster could distinguish Adobe Air access of the website from normal visitor browsing? Perhaps by adding something to the URL requests I make in the application?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using Air / HTML JavaScript?
If not then you have to use the Google Analytics Flash SDK.

In any case, Google Analytics allows custom variables to be tracked. 
You can create a variable "Custom-Device-Type"  and set it as "Out of browser" for air, and "In Browser" for browser (or just don't set it).

Its custom, you can set whatever you want.
it goes into your Google Analytics tracking code.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/08/28/20-ways-use-custom-variables/